# FROM keyword not found where expected when I'm trying to run a query containing a CASE expression in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is the database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztcVf.jpg)

I need to display employee’s last name and first name, followed by salary+commission if commission
is not null, else display salary only.

I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SALARY, COMMISSION
  2  CASE COMMISSION WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN SALARY+COMMISSION
  3  ELSE SALARY
  4  END AS TOTAL_SALARY FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

And it's always showing me the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JRsC.png)

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use `NVL`:

```
SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SALARY, COMMISSION,
  salary + nvl(commission, 0) as total_salary
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

---

Or `coalesce`:

```
salary + coalesce(commission, 0)
```

---

Or `case` (but valid, this time):

```
salary + case when commission is null then 0
            else commission
       end
```